# My answer about using flags as weapons remains deleted. I would like it undeleted please

Tags: discussion, moderators

I answered [this question about using flags as weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/185417/627) with the Pulitzer prize winning photo of exactly that.  I included an encouragement for Americans to vote.  I expected some down votes from people upset by the photo but was surprised to get a moderator level deletion from Monty_Wild without explanation.

I presume that an exhortation to vote was considered offensive enough to warrant deletion.  I removed that and replaced it with a musing about societal symbols used as weapons.  I would like my idea to be undeleted please.  Or if it must stay deleted, explain why.

Comment: Just as an update: It looks like the answer was undeleted by the some moderator last week after the discussion began, so it looks like the problem's been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bulk of the post, with or without the photo had little to do with elections. On top of that it is about the only answer that actually displays a flag being used as a weapon.

I understand that some people may feel offended by seeing the flag of their country being used as a weapon. Doesn't mean that did not happen, and there is no call in the post for it to be used that way again.

I believe it should be undeleted. Unfortunately since it deleted by a moderator, I cannot vote to undelete it.

Comment: You are referring to the edited version of the answer. The original one was just a call to the poll stations, with no attempt to answer the OP question

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I am referring to the first version of the post. The question asks if flags can be used as weapons, the post has a picture of one being used as a weapon. A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: The text accompanying the picture was not addressing the question at all. And a picture alone without no explanation is too low quality of answer, no matter how famous the picture might be.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica "Can Flags be used as weapons?" albeit short and simple is not showing a flag famously used as a weapon a sufficient "yes and heres an example"? What kind of explanation is needed beyond they exist? the rest would be fluff regardless to fill an arbitrary word count to not be low quality? The original state of the post looks fine if a bit political to me.